# If $F\subseteq X$ is closed and $K\subseteq X$ is compact, then the set $F+K$ is closed in $X$, if $X$ is a topological vector space

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, operator-theory, topological-vector-spaces

The following question is from my assignment in operator theory and I am not able to prove the assertion that is asked.

Let $X$ be a topological vector space. Show that if $F\subseteq X$ is closed and $K\subseteq X$ is compact, then the set $F+K$ is closed in $X$.

Well in my class notes, not much is said regarding the compact subsets of topological vector space. So, I am not able to think which proposition I should be using to ground my proof on.

Please help me in proving this question.

Comment: What definition of *closed* are you using? How about *compact*? How is the set $F+K$ defined? These are subsets of a topological vector space over what field? The process of solving a problem like this usually involves unpacking and writing these things down.

Comment: It stands to reason that in order to show a set is closed, we show that its complement is open

Comment: @AnIsomorphicTeen And how should I do that?

Comment: I guess you could also use the fact that a set is closed if its equal to its closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $F+K$ is closed in $X$, we need to show that its complement, $(F+K)^c$, is open in $X$. Let $x\in (F+K)^c$. Then, $x\not\in F+K$, so there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U\cap (F+K)=\varnothing$. This means that for all $y\in U$ and all $z\in K$, we have $y+z\not\in F$.

Since $K$ is compact, it is covered by finitely many neighborhoods, say $U_1,\dots, U_n$. Then for each $i$, we have $U_i\cap K\neq \varnothing$, and hence there exists $z_i\in K$ such that $z_i\in U_i$. It follows that
$$[U\cap (F+K) \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n (U\cap U_i) - z_i\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n (U\cap U_i) - K.]$$
Since $U\cap (F+K)=\varnothing$, it follows that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n (U\cap U_i) - K=\varnothing$. But each set $U\cap U_i$ is open, so $\bigcup_{i=1}^n (U\cap U_i)$ is also open. Therefore, $\bigcup_{i=1}^n (U\cap U_i) - K=\varnothing$ implies that $K=\varnothing$, which is a contradiction. We conclude that $x\in (F+K)^c$ cannot be in the interior of $(F+K)^c$, so $(F+K)^c$ is open and $F+K$ is closed.

Comment: I am not able to deduce $ U\cap (F+K) \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n (U\cap U_i) - z_i$. Can you please give some explanation for this line?